# Probabilistic set for very low probability

Tags: data-structures, bloom-filter

I'm looking for a set data structure that's optimised for a very low probability that an item is part of the set.

The use case is the Gnip/Twitter compliance firehose where we get approx 1,000 events per second (that's deletions from all of Twitter). We have a table of, let's say 10 million stored tweets (growing by that amount each year), and if an item appears in the firehose I have to delete it. I'm guessing there will be a match every 100,000 seconds (to pull a number out of the air).

I had thought of a bloom filters, possibly several chained, but given that there's a very low chance of a hit, I'm always going to need to go through the entire chain and things would eventually get linear.

Is there a good sublinear data structure for this?

Comment: Have you tried using a hash table?

Comment: The hash table will linearly increase in size, which I'm trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see the problem. It seems to me that if checking the Bloom filter tells you that you have the tweet stored, you then look up that tweet in your data store. If it's there, you delete it. If it's not there, you don't delete it.

You have 10 million stored tweets, and you expect it to grow by about 10 million per year. So build a Bloom filter that has a capacity of a billion, with a 0.1% probability of false positives. According to the [Bloomfilter calculator](http://hur.st/bloomfilter?n=1000000000&p=.001), that will cost you 1.67 gigabytes.

Understand, that "false positives" number assumes that the filter contains the 1 billion keys. When your filter is very sparsely populated, the probability of false positives is much lower.

If you're getting a thousand tweets per second and the Bloom filter has a false positive rate of 0.1%, then in the worst case you'll get an average of one false positive per second. So once per second your code will have to hit the database to determine if the tweet is there.

But it'll be many years before you get to that. With only 10 million existing records and a growth rate of 10 million per year, it'll be 10 years before the filter is even 10% full. You could probably drop the filter size to 500 million (860 MB), and still not notice a big hit due to false positives.

Comment: I've not looked too closely at the probabilities; it sounds like a vanilla Bloom filter could do the job. I just thought I'd check to see if there was another data structure that was designed for the 'improbable' case. Thanks very much for your answer, I'll try it out.

Answer (score 0):

A Bloom Filter should be fine, assuming that it fits in memory. If it won't fit completely in memory, consider using the solution described in [this paper](http://static.usenix.org/events/hotstorage11/tech/final_files/Bender.pdf).

Alternatively, if you really want to squeeze a bit extra performance, you can use a [Cuckoo Filter](https://www.cs.cmu.edu/~dga/papers/cuckoo-conext2014.pdf), but it will be harder for you to find an open source implementation; here is one in [Go](https://github.com/seiflotfy/cuckoofilter).